# get values in specific cell values after transposing data in python. I dont want to append the values but start getting them on row 5 column 20

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I do not want to append values. I want these values to get inserted in row 5 column 20.

```
data = []     
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=sheet.max_row, values_only=True):   
    data.append(row)
    
transposed_data = list(zip(*data))

for row in transposed_data:       
   sheet.append(row)
```

This code works to transpose the data but what i can use instead of the code below to get this data in row number 5 and column 20 of same sheet ?

```
sheet.append(row) # -- I dont want to append
```

Comment: So you basically want to transpose your data? Your code contradicts your explanation above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`iter_cols`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_cols) to transpose your data :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx")
ws = wb.active # or wb["SheetName"]

SR, SC = 5, 20 # start row/col
    
for i, col in enumerate(
    ws.iter_cols(min_row=2, values_only=True), start=SR):
    for j, v in enumerate(col, start=SC):
        ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value = v
    
wb.save("file.xlsx")
```

Output (*file.xlsx*):

[image]